# Android - Remove the last incomplete line in .txt file

Tags: android

The app records the sensor data and write the data into a .txt file into the phone SD card.

During the data collection process, one may press the stop button anytime to stop writing.

The relevant writing part is as follows:

```
    myFile = new File("/sdcard/ResearchData/"
                            + txtData.getText() + ".txt");
                    myFile.createNewFile();

                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(myOutWriter);
                    myPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(myBufferedWriter);

myPrintWriter.write(currentTime - startTime + " " + acceleration[0]
                    + " " + acceleration[1] + " " + acceleration[2] + "\n");
```

Once the STOP button is pressed, the following codes are executed.

```
myOutWriter.close();
fOut.close();
```

The codes are functioning okay, but the only problem is that because one may press STOP anytime, so the last line of the .txt file is always INCOMPLETE. Due to the need for data analysis, I need the data to be a nice rectangular matrix. Thus, **I need to remove the last incomplete line. How may I do it?**

Or solve this question from another angle. Can I make the STOP button synchronous to the writing process? i.e., after one line has been completely written in, then the STOP is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable of `bool` type which is initially `false` and let's call it `isStopPressed`.

In button's down event, you should assign it to `true`.

I assume you create your file inside a top function, and modify this file inside `onSensorChanged()` function.

Then, after this line

```
myPrintWriter.write(currentTime - startTime + " " + acceleration[0]
                    + " " + acceleration[1] + " " + acceleration[2] + "\n");
```

you need a conditional like,

```
if(isStopPressed) {
   mSensorManager.unregisterListener([Your Sensor Listener]);
   myOutWriter.close();
   fOut.close();
}
```

This will provide you the most comprehensive, valid interval for your needs.

Comment: yes, ur assumptions are all valid in my case. So your idea is: once stop button is pressed, you turn off all the sensors so that the onSensorChanged() method won't be called? Can this ensure that the last line of data has been COMPLETELY written in?

Comment: Yes because you unregister sensor listener and close file after the last line is written.

Answer (score 1):

You may try setting up a boolean flag, like `isStopped` to indicate the STOP button is pressed.
When the STOP button is pressed, set the `isStopped` flag to true.
In your file writing part, check the `isStopped` flag. if it's true, exit the loop and close the file. Otherwise, the code can continue writing lines to the file.

Comment: No. Not working. What you said is exactly what I have done. By right, it should work, but somehow the writing process will still be interrupted.

Comment: Can you try adding `myOutWriter.flush();` before `myOutWriter.close();` and see if it helps?